# my electron app has a white screen when opened on other computers after being packaged

Tags: node.js, json, express, axios, electron

My electron app is loading normally on my machine, but when I package it and send it to another computer, the screen is white and does not render, here's my electron:

```
const { app, BrowserWindow } = require('electron');
const childProcess = require('child_process');

//vai conectar o servidor node.js quando o app for eexecutado
app.on('ready', () => {
    
    const serverProcess = childProcess.spawn('node', ['./app']);
  
    serverProcess.stdout.on('data', (data) => {
      console.log(`----->  : ${data}`);
      
    });
  
    serverProcess.stderr.on('data', (data) => {
      console.error(`ERROR ==> : ${data}`);
      
    });
  });

function createWindow() {


  const win = new BrowserWindow({
    width: 800,
    height: 600,
    show:false, 
    webPreferences: {
      nodeIntegration: true
    }, 
    icon: __dirname + "/logo.png"
  });


  win.loadURL('http://localhost:3030/'); 

  win.once("ready-to-show", () =>{
    win.show();
  })
}

app.whenReady().then(createWindow);
```

my package.json:

```
{
  "name": "gerador-de-boletos",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "main": "main.js",
  "scripts": {
    "make": "electron-forge make",
    "start": "electron-forge start",
    "package": "electron-forge package"
  },
  "author": "Pedro Stahl",
  "license": "ISC",
  "build": {
    "productName": "Gerador de Boletos"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "axios": "^1.4.0",
    "boleto-banco-brasil": "^0.0.7",
    "date-fns": "^2.30.0",
    "ejs": "^3.1.9",
    "electron-squirrel-startup": "^1.0.0",
    "express": "^4.18.2",
    "mysql2": "^3.5.2",
    "node": "^16.20.0",
    "sequelize": "^6.32.1"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@electron-forge/cli": "^6.4.1",
    "@electron-forge/maker-deb": "^6.4.1",
    "@electron-forge/maker-rpm": "^6.4.1",
    "@electron-forge/maker-squirrel": "^6.4.1",
    "@electron-forge/maker-zip": "^6.4.1",
    "@electron-forge/plugin-auto-unpack-natives": "^6.4.1",
    "electron": "^26.0.0",
    "nodemon": "^3.0.1"
  },
  "config": {
    "forge": {
      "extraResources":[
        {
          "from": "./views",
          "to": "views"
        }
      ],
      "makers": [
        {
          "name": "@electron-forge/maker-zip",
          "config": {
            "overwrite": true
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  },
  "description": ""
}
```

I'm using node with express to make the backend function, using axios to make the connection with an api, via endpoint, here's a summary of my code in node:

```
const axios = require('axios');
const path = require('path');
const express = require ('express');
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
const querystring = require('querystring');
const fs = require('fs');
const https = require('https');
const { BBClient } = require('boleto-banco-brasil');
var dateFns = require("date-fns");

//lê o arquivo que contêm os clients
const userPath = path.join(__dirname, 'user.json');
const clients = JSON.parse(fs.readFileSync(userPath, 'utf8'));

const dadosPath = path.join(__dirname, 'dados.json');
const dados = JSON.parse(fs.readFileSync(dadosPath, 'utf8'));



const clientId = clients.client_id;
const clientSecret = clients.cliente_secret;

//cria o basic que é a união do clientId e clientSecret 
const encodedCredentials = Buffer.from(`${clientId}:${clientSecret}`).toString('base64');


const bbClient = new BBClient({
    BB_API_KEY: 'XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX',
    BB_BASIC_CREDENTIALS: 'Basic ' + encodedCredentials,
    BB_CONVENIO: dados.convenio,
    BB_WALLET: dados.carteira,
    BB_WALLET_VARIATION: dados.variacao,
    BB_AGENCIA: dados.agencia,
    BB_CONTA: dados.conta,
    ENVIRONMENT: 'prod'
  });

const app = express();

const viewsPath = path.join(__dirname, 'views');
app.set('views', viewsPath);


app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));
app.use(bodyParser.json());


//setando ejs como engine padrão
app.set('view engine', 'ejs');

app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname,"public")));


//Lê o arquivo de onde são passados os caminhos dos diretórios, para poder alterar quando mudar de maquina
const configPath = path.join(__dirname, 'dir.json');
const config = JSON.parse(fs.readFileSync(configPath, 'utf8'));

//variável que tem o caminho de onde serão adicionados os arquivos txt
const folderPath = config.arquivosTXT;

//variável com o caminho para onde serão mandados os boletos excluídos 
const zzzPath = config.pastaExcluidos;

//variável com o caminho para onde vão os boletos em pdf gerados
const folderPathBol = path.join(__dirname,'tmp', 'uploads', 'boletos');



//variáveis para criar o pop up na tela de resposta após os boletos serem gerados.
let popUp, title;
let selectedFiles;
let accessToken, jsonObject, jsonObject2, nome, valor, dataVenc, numeroContrato, data;
let somador = 1;
let index = 0;

//dados bancários 
const agencia = dados.agencia;
const conta = dados.conta;
const variacao = dados.variacao;

//essa function serve para procurar o ultimo registro de boleto gerado, aumentando o range de busca caso não encontre.
async function teste() {

    const incremento = 3;
    let intervalo = 1;
    let checaUltimoIntervalo = false;
    let maiorNumeroBoleto;
    let boletosOrdenados;
    const ontem = (0, formataData)((0, dateFns.addDays)(new Date(), -intervalo), 'dd.MM.yyyy');

    do {
        return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        
            let config = {
                method: 'get',
                maxBodyLength: Infinity,
                url: `XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX`,
                headers: { 
                'Accept': 'application/json', 
                'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + accessToken,
                },
    
            httpsAgent: new https.Agent({ rejectUnauthorized: false }),
    
            data : data
            };
        
      
            axios.request(config)
            
            .then(response => {
                const purchase = (response.data);
    
                boletosOrdenados = purchase.boletos.sort((a, b) => a.numeroBoletoBB.localeCompare(b.numeroBoletoBB));
    
                // console.log(boletosOrdenados);
    
                maiorNumeroBoleto = boletosOrdenados[boletosOrdenados.length - 1].numeroBoletoBB;
    
                console.log("nosso numero: " + maiorNumeroBoleto);
    
                if (purchase) {
                    checaUltimoIntervalo = true;
                }
    
                intervalo += incremento;
                
                resolve(maiorNumeroBoleto); //resolve a promessa

            }) .catch(error => {
    
            console.log(error);
            reject(error); // Rejeite a promessa em caso de erro
    
            });
        });
    } while (!checaUltimoIntervalo);
}

//página inicial onde pode ser selecionados os boletos que serão gerados.
app.get('/', (req, resp) =>{

    fs.readdir(folderPath, (err, files) => {

        if (err) {
            resp.status(500).send('Erro interno do servidor.');
                    
        } else {
            resp.render('index', { files });
        }
    });
});

//There is code here but I'm hiding it as it's not relevant

app.listen(3030, () => {
    console.log("servidor iniciado na porta 3030: http://localhost:3030");
 });
```

help me please i don't know what else to do.

Comment: That would be useful if you could check if there is an error in the console on the white screen app.

Comment: nothing appears in the console, but I tried to render a file now instead of a url and it rendered normally, so I believe that the error is happening in the way I am trying to load the express routes.